# Laravel. Echo object properties in asset

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

How do I echo variables in html asset element?

My element:

```
<img src="{{ asset("cropp/$review->user->profile_picture") }}" alt="" />
```

Result i get is:

```
<img src="{{ asset("cropp/{object}->profile_picture") }}" alt="" />
```

Only format i can use:

```
<img src="{{ asset("cropp/$review->image") }}" alt="" />
```

My img src can't undefine that I'm using DB relationship.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use object properties in `asset()` method you can use this:

```
<img src="{{ asset("cropp/" . $review->user->profile_picture) }}" alt="" />
```

or this:

```
<img src="{{ asset("cropp/{$review->user->profile_picture}") }}" alt="" />
```

Comment: @evaldus To further the understanding the syntax of blade, take note that `{{ asset("text") }}` translates into `echo asset("text");`